# Как изменить порядок объектов внутри объекта по значению

Tags: сортировка, объекты

Есть объект:

```
const input = {
      nickname: {value: 'nick', id: 1},
      city: {value: null, id: 2},
      country: {value: 'Russia', id: 3},
      postal_code: {value: '', id: 4},
    };
```

Нужно отсортировать объект так, чтобы на выходе получилось такое:

```
 const output = {
      nickname: {value: 'nick', id: 1},
      country: {value: 'Russia', id: 3},
      postal_code: {value: '', id: 4},
      city: {value: null, id: 2},
    };
```

Сначала должны быть объекты с `value`, а дальше объекты с `value ''` и `null`. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: "Нужно отсортировать объект" - Зачем? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: нужно откинуть все вэлью с пустыми строками и нуллами вниз а вверх поднять объекты с данными

Comment: @StasVerevkin Зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```js
const input = {
      nickname: {value: 'nick', id: 1},
      city: {value: null, id: 2},
      country: {value: 'Russia', id: 3},
      postal_code: {value: '', id: 4},
    };
    
const output = Object.fromEntries( 
                 Object.entries(input).sort(
                  (a,b) => {
                       if (a[1].value != null && b[1].value != null) return 0;
                       if (a[1].value == null) return 1;
                       if (b[1].value == null) return -1;}
                  )
               );
    
console.log(output)
```